# Value assignment to a variable outside of a function in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried to assign a value in aspx.cs file.

```
static String cnn;
cnn = "hi";
```

I get an error:

> cnn is a field but used as a type

I have added the code above all functions in the class (not inside page load or any other event handler).

Why do I get this error and how can I fix it??

Answer (score 3):

You can't refer to `cnn` outside of a function, except when declaring the field.

If you want to declare and initialize the field, this *can* be done in one line:

```
static string cnn = "hi";
```

Note on style - in C#, use `string`, not `String`.

Comment: It is still not working and I get the same error I mentioned ago

Comment: @SriniVas - Is this happening on this line? Are you certain? It could very well be happening somewhere else where `cnn` is referenced. Where are you trying to use it?

Comment: That is only place where I used cnn.

Comment: @SriniVas - since this is essentially identical to what Adil posted in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14200741/1583), how come that answer worked and this one didn't?

Comment: I am not sure why it didn't.

Comment: @Adil suggested "String" & Oded suggested "string" (that's the only difference I can see)

Comment: @Csharp - When compiled, `string` becomes `System.String`, which is exactly what `String` is. It _cannot_ account for the different result.